# When a flow changes its character from time-periodic to chaotic?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In [this](http://www.featflow.de/en/benchmarks/cfdbenchmarking/flow/dfg_benchmark1_re20.html) simple benchmark describing the flow around a disc in the plane with stationary bc, for low Reynolds numbers the solution is stationary and for higher RN it is [periodic in time](http://www.featflow.de/en/benchmarks/cfdbenchmarking/flow/dfg_benchmark2_re100.html). Is there a theory saying, by which RN periodicity disappears and the solution(s) become(s) completely chaotic (if it happens at all)?

Comment: You might like this [very nice review article](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.fl.28.010196.002401) that covers nearly all aspects of the cylinder wake problem.

Comment: @horchler: I think you should make yours a regular answer to this question so people can upvote it.